# Distinct of one column from a two column table in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to get a unique list of a table with two columns ...

Table `snapshot`:

```
ITEM   DISP
-----------------
903996 , 1600
903996 , 3D13
123045 , 1D23
450300 , 3D14
450300 , 3DAD
```

The output I need is the following

```
ITEM     DISP
-----------------
903996 , 1600
123045 , 1D23
450300 , 3D14
```

I know that in SQL Server 2005 the `ROW_NUMBER` is very helpful for this type of problem by I'm working in SQL Server 2000 and this function does not exist.

This is my idea for SQL Server 2005:

```
    Select  [ITEM],[DISP]
FROM (
SELECT 
       [ITEM]
      ,[DISP]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ITEM] ORDER BY [ITEM]) as RowNumber
  FROM [TABLE]
) WHERE RowNumber =1
```

How can I do this in SQL Server 2000?

Thanks

Comment: How do you want rows to be sorted when the ITEM columns are equal? SELECT ITEM, MIN(DISP) AS DISP FROM [TABLE] GROUP BY ITEM will work if you're not too picky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `MIN()` with `GROUP BY`:

```
select item, min(disp)
from snapshot
group by item
```

See [SQL fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9cb1b/1)

Result:

```
|   ITEM | DISP |
-----------------
| 123045 | 1D23 |
| 450300 | 3D14 |
| 903996 | 1600 |
```